# Searchable Dropdownlist by using Select2 liberary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make my dropdownlist searchable. I followed [this](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Effortlessly-Add-search-functionality-to-asp-net) example and downloaded Select 4.0.3 version. But my code is not working. It shows the simple dropdown with no writing or searching.. same as asp:dropdownlist control.

My code is bellow. Will be very thankful if any idea or help.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Select2/select2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { $("#myDropDownlistID").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:dropdownlist id="myDropDownlistID" width="300px" runat="server">
            <asp:listitem text="Select Color"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Red"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Green"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Blue"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Pink"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Yellow"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Lime"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Black"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Purple"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Deep Pink"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Orange"></asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem text="Light Pink"></asp:listitem>
        </asp:dropdownlist>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I expect in the final html your select tag is not called `myDropDownlistID` but maybe `form1_myDropDownlistID`. The actual id used in the browser is available in ClientID. Otherwise check your browsers  dev-console for errors

Answer (score 0):

In Web Forms the IDs of the controls aren't exactly what you state. 
They have a prefix based on the form you put them in to so you have to do this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { $("#<%=myDropDownlistID.ClientID%>").select2(); });
```

Comment: Thanks misha. but it is working which I stated in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. Its my little mistake. the cdn address was wrong. I reference my own jquery and that works.

I downloaded [this](http://www.codingfusion.com/Download/128471736) which is also working perfectly except cdn address. I reference "jquery-2.1.0.js" instead of cdn and it works fine.

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Telerik ASP.NET ComboBox. Type one character and it will find the first item containing that letter. ([See this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx))

Comment: Yes I know I can work with Telerik but I am not using Telerik controls at all in my project.